# How can I import type information for Flow with RequireJS-loaded modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, flowtype

I have a large web project that currently uses RequireJS for module loading in development and optimization for production. Before Flow, files look something like this:

```
define(function(require) {
  const React = require('react');

  class Foo extends React.Component {
    // [...some component code]
  }

  return Foo;
});
```

I'm interested in adding Flow to my system. I've got it working, more or less, but I'm missing some of the key features because I can't convince Flow that my required modules are the actual modules.

Given the following code, I'd expect a type error, but it only works if I add `import * as React from 'react'` to the top of my module, allowing flow to recognize the React.Component type. But that isn't compatible with loading modules through RequireJS.

I've tried creating various definitions for `define`, but I don't know how to tell flow that the require object being passed as the function's argument is the "real" require.

Sample code:

```
// @flow
define(function(require) {
  const React = require('react');

  type Props = {
    foo: string
  }

  type State = {
    bar: string
  }

  class Foo extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    someMethod(): void {
      this.setState({
        bar: 1 // should trigger a type error
      });
    }

    // [...other component code]
  }

  return Foo
}
```

In my `flow-typed` file for RequireJS:

```
declare function define(module: ((require: string) => any) => any): void;
```

Comment: Have you considered writing your modules in ES6 module syntax and just compiling the files to AMD with Babel? Flow doesn't know what AMD modules are, so you'd be much better off authoring in a format it can follow.

Answer (score 2):

Flow only knows how to parse and follow types within CommonJS and ES6 module files. There are a few super hacky comment-based solutions in https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/28, but at the end of the day it just wasn't designed for AMD, so you're essentially writing a piece of your app inside a comment in order to make Flow see your file as CommonJS instead of AMD.

I understand that AMD is important for your workflow, so it seems like drastic changes to your build process are probably a no-go? Given that, the only real option that comes to mind for me would be for your to change your scripts to be authored as ES6 modules, but then compiled to AMD modules to later be bundled. Babel could for instance do this using its AMD output support, then those AMD modules could be bundled up as usual.

It's definitely painful and a decent amount of work no matter what way you look at it. AMD is just not common in modern-day tooling, at least not as an authoring format.